# kurento media server not recording remote audio

Tags: webrtc, recording, kurento

I have extended tutorial one to one call for recording.

Original http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials.html#webrtc-one-to-one-video-call

Extended https://github.com/gaikwad411/kurento-tutorial-node

Everything is fine but recording the remote audio.

When caller and callee videos are recorded, in the caller video recording callee voice is absent and vica versa.

I have searched kurento docs and mailing lists but did not find solution.

The workarounds I have in mind
1. Use ffmpeg to combine two videos
2. Use composite recording, I will also need to combine remote audio stream.

My questions are

1) Why it is happening, because I can hear the remote audio in ongoing call, but not in recording. In recording I can hear my own voice only.

2) Is there another solution apart from composite recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal behaviour. When you connect a `WebRtcEndpoint` to a `RecorderEndpoint`, you only get the media that the endpoint is pushing into the pipeline. As the endpoint is one peer of a WebRTC connection between the browser and the media server, the media that the endpoint pushes into the pipeline is whatever it receives from the browser that has negotiated that WebRTC connection.

The only options that you have, as you have states already, are post-processing or composite mixing.

Comment: Can we append another audio stream to same webRtcEndPoint?, because doing that will fix the problem without composite recording.

Comment: @SachinG. No, that's what the `Composite` media element is used for.